# Programmatically load dialog in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create dialogs in jQuery Mobile that appear when you click on a Google Maps marker.

Sample URL: http://cyclestreets.darkgreener.com/location/ (scroll to a London, UK location to see markers).

I've got part of the way there, with this code:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map_marker, 'click', function() {
     $.mobile.changePage({ url: $("#photo"), data: "id=" + marker.id, type: "GET"}, 'pop', false, true);
 });
```

But, a few issues to do with styling and data:

1. The dialog that appears is full-screen. Is there any way I can make it part-screen, [like the default jQuery Mobile dialogs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html), and like the About and Prefs dialogs [on my home page](http://cyclestreets.darkgreener.com/location/)?
2. There isn't a close link in the header - which again, [there is in the default jQuery mobile dialog](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html). Can I ensure this appears, short of adding it by hand?
3. In the dialog's `.live()` event, how can I pick up the data that I have passed to it?

Comment: I fixed the first two of these by adding `$("#photo").dialog({ autoOpen: false });` after document load, and the third with this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272174/jquery-flow-of-events - I can't see an answer link to add this as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
function openPopup(element_id)
{
    $.mobile.changePage(element_id, { transition: "pop", role: "dialog", reverse: false } );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [beta 1](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/06/20/jquery-mobile-beta-1-released/), to get a `div` to appear as a dialog, use the `data-role="dialog"` attribute on the `div` instead of `data-role="page"`.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that jquery dialogs require that there be  data-role content and header divs for the styling to be applied appropriately. This will give you the full dialog with the close button in the header.

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="dialog" >
<div data-role="header"><h3>Oops!</h3></div>
<div data-role="content">
    <p>You done screwed up, partner!</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have the same problem, ive done what JT has said but the close button doesnt work.