# jQuery flow of events

Tags: jquery

In pseudocode, here's what I want to do:

1. Add a bunch of markers to a Google Map
2. Add a click listener to each marker - the listener opens a jQuery Mobile dialog page
3. *Once the dialog page is live* (important for layout purposes), make an Ajax call and set the `src` attribute of an `img` tag, using an ID attached to the marker.

I'm finding managing the flow of events a bit difficult, though.

```
// Set up value of HTML elements inside dialog
// Should call after the dialog is live,
// otherwise layout breaks horribly. 
function setUpPhoto(id) {
    // Cut for brevity: Ajax call to get URL.
    $('#photo-image').attr({ src: image_url  });
}
// Add a map marker and listeners
function addNewMarker(v) { 
    var map_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: v.latlng,
       title: v.caption
    });
    map_marker.setMap(map); 
    // Add a click listener for each marker
    // This should show the dialog, and then set it up, using the appropriate ID.                           
    google.maps.event.addListener(map_marker, 'click', function() {
        // Show the dialog
        $.mobile.changePage($("#photo"), 'pop', false, true);
        // ISSUE - how to call this only after the dialog is live?
        setUpPhoto(v.id);
        // ... could attach it like this, but how to do for each marker?
        $('#photo').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) { 
            getIndividualPhoto(v.id, '');
    });
    });
 }
 $.each(data.marker, function(i,v) {
     addNewMarker(v);
 });
```

This is simplified code - the actual page where I'm having the issue is at http://cyclestreets.darkgreener.com/location/ (scroll to a London, UK location to see some markers)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't worry... figured it out, I think. (Short answer: set a global variables to set `v.id` on marker click, and then have a global handler for `$('#photo').live` which references the global variable.)

Comment: I rolled back the changes you made to your post. The StackOverflow way of doing this is to answer your own question yourself. Go ahead and do that, then accept it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I can't actually see a 'Your Answer' box at the bottom, so I can't add an answer. If you want to answer it, I'll accept that!

Comment: I think you need to wait 48 hours. At worst, just leave it like this, someone else might have another nicely formulated answer that you can accept. If not, at least the answer is in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out: set a global variables to set v.id on marker click, and then have a global handler for $('#photo').live which references the global variable.